# Executing System call in PHP to run SCP asks for password, every time, even though SSH key is set up

Tags: php, scp, raspberry-pi

So I am creating a PHP script that uploads an image from my local environment to a remote server. I have my **SSH keys** set up on both ends and if I simply execute the scp command in terminal it sometimes does not ask for password and sometimes it does. Also, for some reason, it takes about 30-60 seconds to return a result of the **scp** command.

```
<?php 
    $result = system("scp /home/pi/camImage1.jpg username@<myserver>:~/public_html/folder1/innerfolder/camImage.jpg");
    echo $result;
?>
```

Whenever I use it on the php side, it always asks for password. Any suggestions on what the heck is going on?

Comment: take a look at [PHP SSH2 library](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.ssh2.php). It can make your life easier if you're trying to do SSH stuff in PHP.

Comment: The PHP process might be running as a different user, so it wouldn't see your usual key.

Answer (score 0):

As your regular user I am going to guess you have the ssh key in menory (ssh-agent) so it does not require a password after the first connection. When running the scp command with php you did not specify a key, so my guess is you are being asked the user login password and not the ssh key.

IMO, if you wish to run this command via php, I would advise you make a key with no password and on the server disable login via password. You then specify a key with the scp command.

```
scp -i /home/pi/.ssh/your_key ...
```

for additional information on using keys, disabling password authentication, see your distro's documentation.

Comment: This will probably still have issues in that the www-data user doesn't have permissions to access any key the the /home/user hierarchy.  It's not a good idea to do it, but the solution is likely to be creating a key under the www-data user.

Comment: Probably. You might be able to the www-data the proper ownership/group , but I am not sure.